# Index doesnt hit in my query (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

Hello I have folowwing query (I used CURRENT_DATE for query demonstration, later it will be param from function):

```
SELECT *
FROM FOO_TBL
WHERE FOO_VERSION_FROM <= CURRENT_DATE
AND (FOO_VERSION_TO >= CURRENT_DATE) OR (FOO_VERSION_TO IS NULL)) 
AND (FOO_ACTIVE_FROM IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY ID;
```

I've created index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX FOO_IDX ON FOO_TBL (FOO_VERSION_FROM, FOO_VERSION_TO, FOO_ACTIVE_FROM )
```

explain (analyze, buffers) command output for that query:

```
"Sort  (cost=7171052.33..7173000.95 rows=979450 width=6999) (actual time=2135.384..2364.861 rows=979517 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: ID"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 212224kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=10380 read=47568, temp read=61082 written=61166"
"  I/O Timings: read=269.324"
"  ->  Seq Scan on plain_subjekt subjekt  (cost=0.00..77435.98 rows=979450 width=6999) (actual time=0.175..733.647 rows=979517 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((FOO_VERSION_FROM <= CURRENT_DATE) AND ((FOO_VERSION_TO >= CURRENT_DATE) OR (FOO_VERSION_TO IS NULL)) AND (FOO_ACTIVE_FROM IS NOT NULL))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 2"
"        Buffers: shared hit=10380 read=47568"
"        I/O Timings: read=269.324"
"Planning time: 0.156 ms"
"Execution time: 2410.941 ms"
```

what I did wrong?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** - **not** just a "simple" explain

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi, I added output from explain (analyze, buffers)

Comment: Your where condition only removes two rows, so it essentially returns the whole table. In that case the index won't help. Your performance problem is the sorting which is done on disk, not the retrieval without an index. You need to increase `work_mem` for that query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Is there a way in Postgres to have it use an index for the `order by` and then filter afterwards?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes it can, but for that `id` would need to be the first column in the index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . so `(id, foo_version_from, foo_version_to, foo_active_from)` might improve performance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, possibly.